# How to change some text in dozer XML during runtime?

Tags: java, xml, dozer

```
<field>
   <a>personIdIn</a>
   <b>personIdIn.numberVal</b>
   <b-deep-index-hint>com.oracle.determinations.server._10_4.***MYTYPE1***.assess.types.NumberDataType</b-deep-index-hint>
</field>
```

I  have the above piece of code which is part of dozer mapping XML. And I'm loading this file during runtime using this code :

```
    List<String> myMappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    myMappingFiles.add("dozerMapping.xml");
    mapper.setMappingFiles(myMappingFiles);
```

Is there anyway to change the `MYTYPE1` during runtime and load it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM Java Library (or SAX) to read and manipulate your XML-File. If you only need your MYTYPE1- information and you have a distinct knowledge of the dozerMapping.xml you can search your document "by hand" and not with a xml-parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Expression Language](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/expressionlanguage.html), but it is resolved at start-up time only.